# How ot specify null to a glsl struct member?

Tags: glsl

Here is my code

```
struct Ray {
        vec3 origin;
        vec3 direction;
        bool hit;
        Sphere object;
        float t;
};
    
struct Sphere {
        vec3 origin;
        float radius;
        BasicMaterial material;
};
```

Now, when I create a Ray,my goal is that the `object` be NULL.

```
Ray r;
r. origin = origin;
r.direction = dir;
r.hit = false;
r.object = NULL;
r.t = FLT_MAX;
```

When I run it, I get
`error C1503: undefined variable "NULL"`
One way I could think of is make a dummy object and initialise with that every time. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like `NULL` doesn't exist in GLSL. See the most recent [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification (HTML)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html).

`Sphere object` is not an object reference. The type of `object`  is the structure `Sphere`. When you assign a variable (`s`) of type `Sphere` to `object`

```c
Sphere s;
```

```c
Ray r;
r.object = s;
```

all the elements of `s` are copied to `r.object`. GLSL has no concept of objects, object references, inheritance or polymorphism.

Hence the element `Sphere object` in the structure `Ray` doesn't make sense. In GLSL you would need to write a function that calculates the intersection of a `Ray` and a `Sphere`:

```c
struct Ray
{
    vec3 origin;
    vec3 direction;
};
    
struct Sphere 
{
    vec3 origin;
    float radius;
    BasicMaterial material;
};
```

```c
bool IntersectRaySphere(in Ray r, in Sphere s, out float t)
{
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Here is the thing, when I check for intersection with each object, I would have to store the closest one for the material (for shading). Though, I think I might be able to find a workaround, like indices for each object, but I wanted to keep it simple and as close to the pseudocode as possible. I would not mind copying a few objects as the number is less than 10. It's more like an educational project and not some industrial grade code.

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore *"I wanted to keep it simple and as close to the pseudocode as possible [...]"* the pseudo code is based on a high-level language. GLSL is low-level similar C. A possibility would be to define a structure that can store any objects. So you can store the objects in an array.

Comment: Yeah that seems like a better idea. I can initialize index to -1 and further update accordingly.